# Hide count of max length of TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I'm trying to hide the max length of a `TextField`.

I have added:

- `counterText: ""`
- `counter: Offstage()`
- `counter: SizedBox.shrink()`

It's working, the only problem is that the size of the `TextField` changes. I have set it in the `sizedbox`, but it doesn't have any effect on the height and width of the `TextField`.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 0, 20),
            child: Text(
              "Father:",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  height: 1.5),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          /*Text(
            "Father:",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 14,
                height: 1.5),
          ),*/
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              child: TextField(
                controller: _fatherhistory,
                maxLength: 1000,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                ),

                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                //maxLines: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust textField height using `contentPadding`.

Set `contentPadding` as `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,40,15,40)`, adjust the top and bottom value to change the size of textField

and you can change size of `cursor` to fit in the textField `cursorHeight: 30`

Answer (score -1):

To address the issue of the TextField size changing when hiding the max length indicator in Flutter, you can use a combination of InputDecoration and constraints within your SizedBox. Here's a modified version of your code that should maintain the size of the TextField regardless of the counterText

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
  Expanded(
    child: Row(
    children: [
      const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 0, 0, 20),
        child: Text(
          "Father:",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 14,
            height: 1.5
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 5),
      Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 60,
          child: TextField(
            controller: _fatherhistory,
            maxLength: 1000,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
              counterText: "", // Hide counter text
            ),
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
            // Applying constraints to maintain the size
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: 60, // Minimum height
              maxHeight: 60, // Maximum height
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
     ),
    ),
  ],
),
```